Window does not receive focus even when brought to the top
I’m working on a program that uses low-level keyboard hooks (LowLevelKeyboardProc) to detect key combinations and switch focus between windows of specific processes. The goal is for the program to move focus to the next or previous window of a set of programs when detecting Shift + E or Shift + Q.
However, when the current window is not my own program's window, the SetForegroundWindow function does not work, so I have to use AttachThreadInput to bring the window to the top. The problem is that the window does not receive focus, so when I send keyboard commands, they still go to the previous window.
How can I enable focus for the window that is on top?
Here is a snippet of the function I am using:
    let target_window =
        self.get_window_by_name(process_id, "Window Name".to_string());

    if let Some(target_window) = target_window {
        unsafe {
            if current_process_id.is_none() {
                ShowWindow(target_window.0, SW_NORMAL);
                SetForegroundWindow(target_window.0);
                SetActiveWindow(target_window.0);
            } else {
                let foreground_window = GetForegroundWindow();
                let foreground_thread_id =
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(foreground_window, std::ptr::null_mut());
                let target_thread_id =
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(target_window.0, std::ptr::null_mut());

                AttachThreadInput(foreground_thread_id, target_thread_id, TRUE);

                BringWindowToTop(target_window.0);
                ShowWindow(target_window.0, SW_NORMAL);
                // SetForegroundWindow(target_window.0);
                // SetFocus(target_window.0);
                SetActiveWindow(target_window.0);

                AttachThreadInput(foreground_thread_id, target_thread_id, FALSE);
            }
        }
    }

Observation:
When current_process_id is None, it means that the current process is my program, so I only execute SetForegroundWindow and everything works. When it is Some, it means that I am in one of the windows I want to transition between, and it does not work correctly.

This isn't a focus issue. You failed to set the foreground window. Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you, and the AttachThreadInput hack stopped working years ago. Now the real question is: Why don't you call RegisterHotKey instead of a costly and complex low-level hook? I would not be surprised if that also grants you foreground activation permission.

I'll take a closer look at the link you provided later. Regarding low-level usage, I usually used it in my applications with WinAPI for keyboard input tracking. I wasn't aware of RegisterHotKey, and it seems useful in this case, better than low-level. I'll test it later.

Why is it complex and costly? I thought it was the most lightweight option possible.

"Why is it complex and costly?" - A low-level hook is one of the few ways that affect global system responsiveness. The entire chain of installed hooks necessarily has to be called in sequence to support input rejection. Every call to a hook function incurs a costly context switch (a low-level hook is called on the thread that installed it). This quickly adds up, for every single keyboard input. A far less intrusive way to monitor keyboard input is Raw Input.

As suggested by @IInspectable in the comments, switching from LowLevelKeyboardProc to RegisterHotKey allowed calling SetForegroundWindow to bring windows to the foreground and focus them to receive keyboard input.
With this change, there was also no need to use AttachThreadInput.
Here is a brief snippet of the updated code:
hotkey.rs
//call in main trehad 
pub struct HotkeyEvent {}

impl HotkeyEvent {
    pub fn register() -> Result<(), ()> {
        unsafe {
            if RegisterHotKey(null_mut(), HOTKEY_ID_Q, MOD_SHIFT as u32, 0x51 as u32) == 0 {
                eprintln!("Failed to register hotkey SHIFT + Q");
                return Err(());
            }
            if RegisterHotKey(null_mut(), HOTKEY_ID_E, MOD_SHIFT as u32, 0x45 as u32) == 0 {
                eprintln!("Failed to register hotkey SHIFT + E");
                return Err(());
            }

            Ok(())
        }
    }

    pub fn start_loop_message() {
        unsafe {
            let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::zeroed();

            while GetMessageW(&mut msg, null_mut(), 0, 0) > 0 {
                if msg.message == WM_HOTKEY {
                // Here, I perform the logic to obtain the ID of the next window 
                //  and call the set_window_foreground function.
                    process_message_hotkey(msg.wParam as u32) 
                }
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
}

pub fn set_window_foreground(
    &self,
    process_id: u32,
    current_process_id: Option<u32>,
) -> Option<bool> {
    let target_window =
        self.get_window_by_name(process_id, "Window Name".to_string());

    if let Some(target_window) = target_window {
        unsafe {
            ShowWindow(target_window.0, SW_NORMAL);
            SetForegroundWindow(target_window.0);
            SetActiveWindow(target_window.0);
        }
    }
    None
}


The call to SetActiveWindow is not required (and probably just fails). See Eventually, nothing is special any more to understand what the "active window" is.
